# RestTemplate.exchange() - Illegal character(s) in message header value

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, base64, resttemplate

I'm getting an `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character(s) in message header value` error when executing the `restTemplate.exchange()` method.

I guess the problem is a huge HTTP header, which internally will be base64 encoded:

> It seems the SDK is using the old "sun.misc.BASE64Encoder" which will breaking a new line "\n" if the encoded string is too long (>76 characters).

[Source](https://github.com/kintone/java-sdk/issues/10#issuecomment-321488606)

My code snippet which produces the error:

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.set("jwt", jwt); // JSON Web Token with length of over 900 characters
HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>("parameters", headers);
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(builder.toUriString(), HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
```

But how can I change the used base64-encoder which is used by the `RestTemplate`?

The stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character(s) in message header value: eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJJc3N1ZXIiLCJhdWQiOi...

at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.checkMessageHeader(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.isExternalMessageHeaderAllowed(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.addRequestProperty(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.addRequestProperty(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.addHeaders(SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:104) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:70) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:596) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:557) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:475) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
```

EDIT:
And while adding the stack trace to my question I found the error: The newline wasn't added by the base64 encoding but by the service that gave me the jwt String...

I guess I could delete my question but maybe somewhen someone will stumble upon the same mistake, so: **Check your header values!**

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
 headers.setAcceptCharset(Arrays.asList(Charset.forName("UTF-8")))
```

or even better would be

```
restTemplate.getMessageConverters()
        .add(0, new StringHttpMessageConverter(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
```

Considering you want to change your charset to **UTF-8**

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't fix the error. I think the base64 encoding of the header is done independently of the HttpMessageConverter.

Comment: My bad! The error indeed was because of a new line in the header but it wasn't added by the encoding but was there before.